# VBA event throws error when pressing a button?

Tags: vba, excel

When i click a button on my worksheet the below event is called.

I get the error 'Type mismatch'

I suspect I need another if statement to stop the original IF being evaluated if the event is due to a button being pressed?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target = Range("D4") Then   'Error is here

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
If Target = Range("D4") Then
```

is equivalent to this

```
If Target.Value = Range("D4").Value Then
```

which clearly is not what you want. You will probably get the error you describe if `Target.Value` happens not to be of the same type as `Range("D4").Value`.

What you want is this:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
```

**EDIT** I just managed to reproduce your error. It occurs if the `Target` range is of a different size than `Range("D4")` i.e. spans more than one cell. As @Dick Kusleiska notes, it also occurs if one of the two is an error value. Maybe it's triggered by other things as well, I don't know. Anyhow, the point is, your `If` condition is wrong!

Comment: I couldn't get that error when they are different types, but I could when one was an error value.  I put =NA() in B4 and got a type mismatch.

Comment: + 1 :) Few minutes doesn't make any difference. An answer is an answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then

    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

**EDIT**:

I would also recommend using Error handling and setting the `.EnableEvents` to false to avoid and possible endless loops :)